# POSTing Data From Windows Phone app to Web Page

Tags: browser, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone 8 app. My app needs to POST some data to a web page that I have on my server. Please note, I am trying to POST to a web *page*, not a web *service*. The reason that I need to POST to a web page is because 1) I'm trying to render some contents in a web page that is currently launched via a WebBrowserTask 2) I am passing a large amount of data to the web page.

From what I can tell, the WebBrowserTask only allows "GET". Now, I'm totally lost in regards to what to do. Is there a was to POST data via a WebBrowserTask? If not, is there a way to serialize my data as JSON and cram it into the query string? I know that's ugly. At the same time, I'm not sure what else to do.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by post to a web page? a web page is a response that you get from a server. Do you mean you want to submit a page with some form data back to the server? Or do you mean fill some form data in a page that was already retrieved?

Comment: I mean POST some data from my Windows Phone app to my web server. The response of the web server should be a web page on the Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `WebBrowser` control then make your request through either `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`. Once you get the html response use the `NavigateToString(string)` method to display the result.

But you can simply use the `Navigate(uri)` method if you only need to specify some query string params.